# Google Cloud Tasks: some tasks remain in queue instead of being processed

Tags: google-cloud-tasks

I have a Google Cloud Task queue (rate: 10/s, bucket: 200, concurrent: 1) that dispatches tasks to a worker in a App Engine service (python 2.7 runtime) Tasks are normally added to the queue about 3-4/s. Each task is processed one at a time (no concurrency)

In general, each task is processed very fast(less than 1sg). Surprisingly, the queue sometimes randomly "pauses" a small subset of 5-20 tasks. New incoming tasks are processed as usual but those ones are blocked and stay on the queue for some minutes, even when worker is idle and might process them. After 7-9 minutes, they are processed automatically without any other interaction. Issue is this delay is too much and not acceptable :(

While "paused", I can manually execute those tasks by clicking on the "Run" button and they are immediately processed. So I'd discard some kind of limitation on the worker side.

I tried redeploying the queue.yaml. I also tried pausing and resuming the queue. Both with no effect.

No errors are notified. Tasks are not retried, just ignored for some minutes.

Has anybody experienced this behavior? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Tasks now uses `gcloud` (Cloud SDK) to manage the queue configuration. `queue.yaml` is a part of the legacy App Engine SDK for App Engine Task Queues. Uploading a `queue.yaml` when using Cloud Tasks may cause your queue to be disabled or paused.

To learn more about queue management see, [Using Queue Management versus queue.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/queue-yaml).
To learn more about migrating from Task Queues to Cloud Tasks, see [Migrating from Task Queues to Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/migrating)

Comment: Thanks for the response. We only use the `queue.yaml` config method and, in fact, queue is active and properly configured. The issue is it doesn't seem "stable"

Comment: Are these tasks experience retries?

Comment: No, they just seem ignored for some minutes. After that interval, they are processed without retries. Tasks don't include any custom ETA.